# How to call a python cgi script from another stript

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi

Although I can see many responses to similar questions, I don't really think they answer mine. Basically, I have a python cgi script and I want to run another script. So for instance, let's say that I want to do the following, to keep it simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3  
print("html_text)
# here call some other Python cgi script which has some other HTML text
```

I just want to simplify the question, so that the answer can focus on what I actually want to understand. Basically, I want to call another python cgi script from my current Python cgi script and for it to print more html (and possibly use data from the previous script that is passed).

What I would actually like to do is to make 3 cgi scripts. The first prints a form. Then this form POSTS the data to the next which does the data checking making sure it is all valid. NOW here is the hard part. I basically want to make sure that if the data is invalid, I want to pass the info back to the first script so that the valid data can be kept in the form (via a POST?) and if it is valid, it executes the next script.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import someotherscript 
print("html_text")

someotherscript.footer()
```

someotherscript.py

```
def footer():
    print("Theo's webpage")
```

Comment: Ah, that could work, but what if instead I would like to use a script to print out a login form first, then POST this to the next script and in that script check if the data is valid, if so redirect to another script, if not redirect to the former script?

Thanks btw :)

Comment: Also, I would like to make sure that if the data isn't valid, I can pass it back to the previous page (via a POST maybe).

Comment: @TheoPavlakou I saw your edits. I think you've added enough new information that you could justify asking a separate question.

Comment: Okay, I'll add a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

If the other script is written in Python, then `exec` should suffice...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3  

print("html_text")
exec(open('/path/to/other/script.py').read())
```

Comment: Can you check my comment above please? :) Thanks

Comment: @TheoPavlakou I'd suggest editing the question to include this information.